# Adding Click Listeners in HTML document for Java FX

Tags: javascript, java, html, javafx

I am currently working on a Java project.  The user interface is written using HTML/JS/CSS and is displayed via JavaFX framework.  I am testing interface-specific functionality both with external browsers (Firefox and Chrome) outside of the Java environment, and within the Java program itself.

I am having a problem adding click listeners for elements within the JavaFX environment.  After writing the code included at the bottom of this post, I tested it internally and externally.  It runs fine externally with Chrome and Firefox, but it does not run in JavaFX --> events are fired correctly outside, but not inside JavaFX.

Code for establishing the listeners:

```
$(function() {
    //set listeners
    $(".eventButton").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        switch (id) {
            case "port_button":
                javaOpenWindow('PortWindow','PortWindow');
                break;
            default:
                console.warn("Functionality for button '"+id+"' not implemented");
                break;

        }
    });

    console.log("Button listeners set");
}
```

HTML Elements:

```
<li id="port_button" class='eventButton'><a href='#' >Port Settings</a></li>
<li class='last eventButton' id='advSettings'><a href='#'>Advanced Settings</a></li>
```

I have not yet found out why the events do not trigger in JavaFX, and as far as I can tell, JavaFX is not throwing any errors or exceptions.

As a note, when I implemented the above without JQuery, the problem still existed.

Can anyone either suggest a solution or a way of finding exactly where the problem is?

---

Here is the Java FX Code.  It first uses the constructors to initialize certain elements, then externally, the initializeWindow method is called to initialize everything else and open the window.

```
private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private WebView webView;
    private WebEngine webEngine;

    private JavascriptLink js;
    private GuiObserver observer;
    private String fName;

private int width;
private int height;

private JavascriptLink parentWindow;
private SimpleBooleanProperty webEngineLoadedProperty;

public Window(String fName) {
    //create the stage and set attributes
    webEngineLoadedProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    js = null;
    parentWindow = null;

    stage = new Stage();
    width = 1200;
    height = 600;

    stage.setWidth(width);
    stage.setHeight(height);

    observer = null;

    this.fName = fName;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param fName filename of html file
 * @param wName name for window
 * @param width of window
 * @param height of window
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws SecurityException 
 * @throws NoSuchMethodException 
 * @throws InvocationTargetException 
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException 
 * @throws IllegalAccessException 
 * @throws InstantiationException 
 */
public Window(String fName,int width, int height, GuiObserver o, Stage s) throws IOException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    this(fName);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    stage = s;
    observer = o;
}

public Window(JavascriptLink parent,String fName,int width, int height, GuiObserver o, Stage s) throws IOException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    this(fName,width,height,o,s);   
    parentWindow = parent;
}

/**
 * Initialize the window and open it
 */
public void initializeWindow() {
    scene = new Scene(new Group());

    //load in the appropriate html file to the scene
    webView = new WebView();
    webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setPrefWidth((double)width);
    webView.setPrefHeight((double)height);


    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {

            if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
              //stage.setTitle(windowName);
              webEngineLoadedProperty.set(true);
            }

          }
        });
    webEngine.load(this.getClass().getResource(fName).toExternalForm());

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setContent(webView);
    scene.setRoot(scrollPane);

    /*stage.setWidth((double)width);
    stage.setHeight((double)height);*/


    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    //add listeners
    setListeners();
}
```

---

EDIT: I have determined that the event listeners are actually behaving correctly, it is the link back to the JavaFX which appears to have been broken after a certain code for some reason.

Comment: try with `.addEventListener`

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists with that as well.

Comment: I assumed you are using `WebView`. You need to paste what you did at the JavaFX side too.

Comment: I have added the code I am using.

Comment: I have determined that the event listeners are actually behaving correctly, it is the link back to the JavaFX which appears to have been broken after a certain code for some reason.